# Android Navigation Component including a graph to deeplink in one included location and not the others

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

Currently the application has a graph `baz` that is shared around the navigation graph via `<include app:graph="@navigation/baz" />`. The `app:startDestination` of `@navigation/baz` is a fragment with a deeplink.

```
<deepLink
            android:id="@+id/bazDeepLink"
            app:uri="https://baz.baz/person/{id}/cow/{cowId}" />
```

The navigation to `@navigation/baz` from around the application works. So does deeplinking to the required fragment and the backstack is created correctly when it is included in one graph only.

However when the `@navigation/baz`graph is included into more than one graph the backstack created by the deeplink relies on the last graph where `<include app:graph="@navigation/baz" />` was placed.

Given:

- root graph `A`
- subgraphs `B, C`
- Shared graph `Baz`.

```
A -> B -> Baz

A -> C -> Baz
```

Current behaviour:

Deeplinking creates the following backstack

`A -> C -> Baz`

Desired behaviour:

Deeplinking would create the following

`A -> B -> Baz`

The ideal state would be that the subgraph Baz can contain the deeplink and be included multiple places in the app. But the deeplink resolves only to `A -> B -> Baz`. Essentially we shouldn't need to create a separate graph just because `Baz` has a deeplink in it. The actual graph `Baz` has many fragments inside of it

Is it possible to deeplink to one specific graph. Include said graph  in other graphs. While maintaining a single backstack that is created only when deeplinking.

Comment: Can you give an example of what kind of a back stack do you expect when you include it in multiple graphs?

Comment: Updated. `Baz` should be able to be used wherever included. Just that under the case of deeplinking it traverses only one specific path of the graph.